# Solve In VBA Looping does not work at some point (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, solver

I'm actually new at VBA. I'm using a looping with solve.

It work untill some point, but then it stops calculating and only shows zeros.

In the case bellow it must repeat 22 times and sort between brands CIH and NW.

Untill Column "S" it went ok, but then started showing only zeros.

[image]

Can anyone help me to discover what is wrong in my code?
Very Thx!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.Hide

MesEscolhido = CmbMes.Text
Sheets("PO Planter").Activate

'VERIFICA O MÊS SELECIONADO
'O VALOR DE k É O MêS ESCOLHIDO
For i = 2 To 13
    If Cells(i, 20) = "X" Then
        k = i + 2
    End If
Next

'TRANSPORTA AS MÁQUINAS PARA O SOLVER
'O VALOR DE j REPRESENTA A QUANTIDADE DE MÁQUINAS DAQUELE CONFIGURADOR
'LinhasPO É A QUANTIDADE DE LINHAS
'QtdProduzir É A QUANTIDADE A SER PRODUZIDA DE MÁQUINAS NAQUELE MÊS
'QtdCIH É A QUANTIDADE A SER PRODUZIDA DE MÁQUINAS NAQUELE MÊS DA CASE
'QtdNH É A QUANTIDADE A SER PRODUZIDA DE MÁQUINAS NAQUELE MÊS DA NEW HOLLAND

Sheets("Solver Planter").Activate
Range("AE6").Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("AG6").Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("PO Planter").Activate
LinhasPO = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
QtdProduzir = 1
QtdCIH = 0
QtdNH = 0
For i = 2 To LinhasPO
    j = Cells(i, k)
    If j > 0 Then
        While j > 0
            Sheets("Solver Planter").Cells(5 + QtdProduzir, 35) = Sheets("PO
            Planter ").Cells(i, 1)"
            Sheets("Solver Planter").Cells(5 + QtdProduzir, 33) = Sheets("PO
            Planter ").Cells(i, 17)"
            Sheets("PO Planter").Activate
            If Sheets("PO Planter").Cells(i, 1) = "CIH" Then
                QtdCIH = QtdCIH + 1
            End If

            If Sheets("PO Planter").Cells(i, 1) = "NH" Then
                QtdNH = QtdNH + 1
            End If
            j = j - 1
            QtdProduzir = QtdProduzir + 1
        Wend
    End If
Next

'INICIA O SOLVER

Sheets("PO Planter").Activate
DiasProduzir = Cells(2, 23).Value
Sheets("Solver Planter").Activate

'DiasProduzir É A QUANTIDADE DE DIAS QUE SERÃO CONSIDERADOS PARA O SOLVER RESOLVER
'Z CONTA OS DIAS DE PRODUÇÃO
'ContaCase Verifica a Quantidade Solicitada de Case
'X Garante o While para os Valores de Case
'Xt Controla a Quantidade Total de Case
'ContaNewHolla Verifica a Quantidade Solicitada de NewHolland
'Y Garante o While para os Valores de NewHolland
'Yt Controla a Quantidade Total de New Holland
'T Controla a quantidade a ser produzida

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    ContaCase = QtdCIH
    ContaNewHolla = QtdNH
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    ContaCase = SpinButton1.Value
    ContaNewHolla = SpinButton2.Value
End If

Z = 1
t = 0
Xt = 0
Yt = 0

For Z = 2 To DiasProduzir
    Z = Z - 1
    'EXECUTANDO O SOLVER PARA A CASE
    X = 1
    For X = 1 To ContaCase
        X = X - 1

        If Z <= DiasProduzir & Xt < QtdCIH Then

            With Worksheets("Solver Planter")
                .Activate

                SolverReset

                SolverOptions AssumeLinear:=True

                'SolverOptions MaxTime:=1800

                'SolverOptions Precision:=1

                SolverOk SetCell:=Range(Cells(1, 7 + Z), Cells(1, 7 + Z)), MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(Cells(6, 7 + Z), Cells(5 + QtdCIH, 7 + Z)), _
                         Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

                SolverAdd cellRef:=Range(Cells(6, 7 + Z), Cells(5 + QtdCIH, 7 + Z)), _
                          relation:=5

                SolverAdd cellRef:=Range(Cells(6, 7), Cells(5 + QtdCIH, 7)), _
                          relation:=1, _
                          formulaText:=1

                SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("$H$3:$AD$3"), _
                          relation:=1, _
                          formulaText:=Range("B1")

                SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("$H$4:$AD$4"), _
                          relation:=1, _
                          formulaText:=Range("B2")

                SolverSolve userFinish:=True
                SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

                For i = 6 To (5 + QtdCIH)
                    If Cells(i, 7 + Z) = 1 Then
                        X = X + 1
                        Xt = Xt + 1
                    End If
                Next
                Z = Z + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next
    'EXECUTANDO O SOLVER PARA A NEW HOLLAND

    Y = 1
    For Y = 1 To ContaNewHolla
        Y = Y - 1
        If Z <= DiasProduzir & Yt < QtdNH Then
            With Worksheets("Solver Planter")
                .Activate
                SolverReset
                SolverOptions AssumeLinear:=True
                'SolverOptions MaxTime:=1800

                SolverOk SetCell:=Range(Cells(1, 7 + Z), Cells(1, 7 + Z)), MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(Cells(6 + QtdCIH, 7 + Z), Cells(5 + QtdCIH + QtdNH, 7 + Z)), _
                         Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

                SolverAdd cellRef:=Range(Cells(6 + QtdCIH, 7 + Z), Cells(5 + QtdCIH + QtdNH, 7 + Z)), _
                          relation:=5

                SolverAdd cellRef:=Range(Cells(6 + QtdCIH, 7), Cells(5 + QtdCIH + QtdNH, 7)), _
                          relation:=1, _
                          formulaText:=1

                SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("$H$3:$AD$3"), _
                          relation:=1, _
                          formulaText:=Range("B1")

                SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("$H$4:$AD$4"), _
                          relation:=1, _
                          formulaText:=Range("B2")
                SolverSolve userFinish:=True
                SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

                For i = (5 + QtdCIH) To (6 + QtdCIH + QtdNH)
                    If Cells(i, 7 + Z) = 1 Then
                        Y = Y + 1
                        Yt = Yt + 1
                    End If
                Next

                Z = Z + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next
Unload Me

End Sub
```